Update dropdown selected value on change in anuglar
I have manually created a  dropdown field without using any input and select tag to meet expected UI. so I will be having three dropdowns for three colors called blue, green and red. If I choose a name 'xyz' from dropdown for color blue then the selectedValueArray should have only "xyz" and then I am changing the dropdown value as name 'xye' the the previous value should be removed and the new value should be added.
but in my case the old selectedValue still exist in the selectedValueArray array. How to remove the previously selected value.
app.component.html
<div [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
 <ul *ngIf="selectedValue; else showSelect">
  <li >{{selectedValue.name}}</li>
</ul>
<ng-template #showSelect>
  <span>Select</span>
</ng-template>
</div>
<div>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before" [overlapTrigger]="true">
<div class="m-10">
  <ul *ngFor="let value of dropdownValues"
    (click)="selectItem(value)" mat-menu-item>
    <li>{{value.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

app.component.ts
 selector: 'app-select'

 dropdownValues = [
  {
  name: 'xyz',
  age: 30,
  },
  name: 'xye',
  age: 30,
  },
  {
  name: 'xyx',
  age: 30,
  }];

  selectItem(value) {
  this.selectedValue = value; 
  this.onSelect.emit(value);
  }

sample.component.html
    <div *ngFor="let color of colors">
    <span>{{color.name}}
    <app-select (onSelect)= "onSelect($event, color)"></app-select>
    </div>

sample.component.ts
    info;
    selectedValueArray = [];
    colors = [{id:1, name: 'blue'}, {id:2, name: 'green'}, {id:3, name: 'red'}];

    onSelect(value, color) {
    this.info  = value;
    this.selectedValueArray.push(this.info);
    console.log(this.selectedValueArray);// here the selectedValue should be passed to an 
    api's payload.

please find the link here for stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-output-eventemitter-ed2k6f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

If you want to clear the previous selections in the array just overwrite the whole array. this.selectedValueArray = [value];. I see a number of issues with your code that will lead to similar bugs down the line. Basically, try to have his few sources of Truth as possible. Don't store the same information in multiple places which have to be manually synchronized in every event handler. For example, why not use a property a set accessor for selectedValue which calls this.onSelect.emit whenever the value changes.

@AluanHaddad can you share your solution as code. so that it will help me to resolve the issue

Every time I don't have time right now and I'm at work station. If you set up a stackblitz containing your code I could take a look, there's no way to tell from what you have the versions of your dependencies and a number of other things. I was simply noting that your approach seems to invite subtle bugs

@AluanHaddad I have updated the code in stackblitz. Please check and provide your valuable solutions. Actually I am stuck and unable to proceed further. Please take a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-output-eventemitter-ed2k6f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

this.selectedValueArray = [this.info]. why are you using an array if only one value is allowed?

@danielRICADO the array should have the selected values for three colors. but the selection is not mandatory. so I am pushing the selected values to the selectedValueArray

if your inputs are not dynamic you should store the selected value of each dropdown seperately or use a keyed object, otherwise when reselecting you need to know the index of the array to update and that'll only work if you force users to select options in a specified order.

@danielRICADO can you please explain the solution as code. I could understand your way but no idea how to implement it

there are too many refactors required in this question, I would suggest finding a tutorial or hoping someone coming across your question has the time to do it for you. Simply put refactor to change the way you store each selection instead of just pushing it into a single array, that shouldn't need a code example as the official angular heroes tutorial will teach you how to do that. start here https://angular.dev/tutorials/learn-angular/1-components-in-angular
